# Undesired vertical space in List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents

How to get rid of that vertical space between caption titles? (space between the second line and the third line).

The figures come from different files that have been \input'ted ;  using \include does not change result.

*Edit: problem is due to figures being in different chapters, not due to coming from different files. So answer is there. Thank you Werner.*

[image]

Minimal example is

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

%\usepackage[labelsep=newline,justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\input{part1.tex}
\input{part2.tex}
\end{document}
```

where part1.tex has two figures and is

```
\blinddocument

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}  
\end{center}
\caption{First input file, first figure}
\label{fig:TrueDistances1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}  
\end{center}
\caption{First input file, second figure}
\label{fig:TrueDistances2}
\end{figure}
```

while part2.tex is

```
\blinddocument

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}  
\end{center}
\caption{Second input file, first figure}
\label{fig:TrueDistances3}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thank you Werner. I was wrong at assuming that it was due to the files coming from different files. It is due to them coming from different chapters.